# Spring Boot JPA OneToMany Update not working

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

My Spring Boot app uses JPA, Hibernate and a MySQL db.

I want to save users with working-times.

User.java

```
@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "user")
@DynamicUpdate
public class User {

@JsonProperty("workingTimes")
@OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<WorkingTime> workingTimes;

...
}
```

WorkingHours.java

```
@Entity(name = "WorkingTime")
@Table(name = "working_time")
public class WorkingTime {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@JsonProperty("id")
private int id;

...
}
```

So there is a third table created by hibernate.

I am able to store users with working times, and the links are set in the third table.

But when I post a JSON-Array with existing and new users / working times, the insert will be stopped. The new elements are not inserted in the database.

How can I update my db with the new entries?

Answer (score 1):

@OneToMany mapped by setting is set to default value "".
The mapped by option is required unless the relationship is unidirectional.
I think you need to set that option for the two-way association to work properly.
So I think @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) will solve the problem.